# Upgrading SignalR 1.0.0-RC1 to 1.0.1 - ScaleoutMessageBus type not found in SignalR.Core - fix?

Tags: c#-4.0, signalr, signalr-hub

My project was successfully using SignalR v1.0.0-RC1 with Redis message bus scale-out.

Upgrading to v1.0.1, I now get the following error:

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ScaleoutMessageBus' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

That is triggered from my Global.asax:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(server, Int32.Parse(port), password, eventKeys);
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scale-out providers were dropped for 1.0.0 and therefore are still gone in 1.0.1.  Since the assemblies are signed you will not be able to use old scale-out assemblies with newer SignalR code.

Scale-out is coming back though, it will be available in the next release 1.1.

Comment: That's kinda accurate. ScaleoutMessage bus is still in 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 it's just not production ready. If you want to use the old version (and we recommend you don't) then you can download the rc3 versions from nuget.